# Is it safe to use 'kill -9 -1' on ubuntu

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, kill, ubuntu-20.04

I am using ubuntu 20.04, and sometimes due to some problems, my system hangs or glitches a bit so I run 'kill -9 -1' on the terminal to kill all the processes and the problems are solved.

My question is:

Is it safe to use that command frequently? Because after running that, all my windows get closed all of a sudden and my screen blacks out for a second or two.

What's the meaning of that command?

What harms can it cause to the system?

What are some useful things I can do with kill command in linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not great, but there are worse things.
Why don't you try find the underlying cause, rather then kill everything?

"Kill" will signal to a program to stop itself. Kill -9 will do as much as possible to stop the program. The -1 does this to all programs.

Generally running "top" will show the processes tying up resources, and then you can kill (or kill -9) the associated ID.  You may be able to "killall programname" as an easier alternative.